# How to change Server side variables in the client side nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side, client-side

So I have this code in api/scraper.js

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

let url = "https://crese.org/distintivo-azul/";

let result;

request(url, (err, response, html) => {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const allText = $("html *").contents().filter(function () {return this.type === "text"}).text();
        
        const texts = ["respeto a la dignidad de las personas", "respect for the dignity of people"]
        result = allText.includes("respeto a la dignidad de las personas")

    }
})

export default function handler(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({result: result})
}
```

It works all, but the *let url* variable, it need to change. I have a form to handle this change, so the user can put the url in the input form from the client side... how can it be change when the user send the url from the client "input form" and change that *let url* var iable in server side.

In simple words "Modifying the url varible that is in api/scraper.js" with the form tag that is in the client side.

Any idea to handle this?

**EDIT**
The client side looks like this

```
    // Automate steps process
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("/api/scraper");

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(Object.values(result))
    return setData(result)
    //console.log(event.target.url.value);
  };

// get results from backend
const [results, setData] = useState([])


return (
    <div>
        <Head>
            <title>Blue Token | Steps</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/logo.png" />
        </Head>

        <div className={styles.minting}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Enter Your website URL</h1>
                <label>We are going to check if you have the requesits</label><br /><br />  
                <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="url" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. You will have to pass in url from client inside body of http request

```
function startScrape(req, res) {
  request(req.body, (err, response, html) => {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      const allText = $("html *")
        .contents()
        .filter(function () {
          return this.type === "text";
        })
        .text();

      const texts = [
        "respeto a la dignidad de las personas",
        "respect for the dignity of people"
      ];
      let result = allText.includes("respeto a la dignidad de las personas");

      res.status(200).json({ result: result });
    }
  });
}

export default function handler(req, res) {
if(req.method==='POST')
  startScrape(req, res);
}
```

### Client

```
const [results, setData] = useState([]);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Here we're passing url inside body of the request which will 
    // be received on the backend

    const response = await fetch("/api/scraper", { method: "POST", body: url });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(Object.values(result));
    return setData(result);
    //console.log(event.target.url.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>Enter Your website URL</h1>
          <label>We are going to check if you have the requesits</label>
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="url"
            name="url"
            placeholder="url"
            value={url}
            onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Also, request package is deprecated, you should use any other package like axios

Comment: req.body.url how this works? can you give me an example with a little script in the client that access this req.body.url?

Comment: @bernardoolisan you mentioned in the question you've input tag you have on your client side ?

Comment: yes, I have one, lemme edit my question so you can the how my client works

Comment: done, the edit is there

Comment: @bernardoolisan I've edited my answer, added the client code.

Comment: You should switch to axios or any other package, request is deprecated

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'm gonna try axios, and also, I understand everything, but the only thing I didn't was... why you take out the req.body.url to req.body?

Comment: @bernardoolisan if I kept req.body.url, I would have to send an object with url property from frontend to server. As you're using fetch on client side, I would've to first use JSON.stringify to send it to server. This saves an extra step..